# Calculation in excel based on unique column values

Tags: excel

Below is a dummy dataset. The real dataset has thousands of rows.

1. I need to calculate average of values in column C for all the unique values in column B.
2. I need unique entries of column B which come in column C's top 10%.

```
A     B C   D 
Adam1 2 50 60
Adam2 1 56 46
Adam3 2 23 32 
Adam4 3 25 56 
Adam5 2 54 46
Adam6 3 45 45
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also please include wanted results. See [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

1. Pivot table!
   Filter: empty,
   Rows: B,
   Columns: empty,
   Values: Average of (C)
2. First you need to make a new column [in top 10 %] with formula `=LARGE([C],ROWS([C])*0.1)<=[@C]`
   Then Pivot table!
   Filter: [in top 10 %] = true,
   Rows: B,
   Columns: empty,
   Values: empty

Comment: Good to hear  how about an upvote, so the kids will eat tonight?